# Replace english characters within bracket

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove English characters if it is in bracket.

```
x = "Бактериологическое исследование отделяемого слизистой оболочки прямой кишки на гонококк (Nesseria gonorrheeae)"
gsub('\\(.*?[a-zA-Z]\\)', '', x)
```

The above code works fine. But if I have multiple brackets, it does not return correct result.

```
x = "Определение полиморфизма A1648G (замена аденина на гуанин в позиции 1648) в гене гликопротеина la (GpIA)"
gsub('\\(.*?[a-zA-Z]\\)', '', x)
```

I want it should return -

```
Определение полиморфизма A1648G (замена аденина на гуанин в позиции 1648) в гене гликопротеина la
```

Comment: Try to use negated [`[^)]*` instead of `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/V7wb8B/1)

Comment: how about `'\\((?:\\w\\s?)+\\)'` in combination with `gsub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small correction:

```
x <- "исследование (исследование) исследование (test) исследование (test) исследование"
gsub('\\([a-zA-Z ]*\\)', '', x)
# [1] "исследование (исследование) исследование  исследование  исследование"
```

Comment: It's unable to remove it from x = "Бактериологическое исследование отделяемого слизистой оболочки прямой кишки на гонококк (Nesseria gonorrheeae)"

Comment: @john, now I added a space.